# boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream, launch client first and wait for server?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have an application that uses boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream to connect to another application via tcp.

My server code is:

```
static auto const flags = boost::archive::no_header | boost::archive::no_tracking;
boost::asio::io_service ios;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint
= boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, endpoint);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

//program stops here until client connects.
acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());
```

and my client is:

```
std::string ip = "127.0.0.1";

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream(ip, "4444");

    if (!stream)
        throw std::runtime_error("can't connect");
```

If the server is launched first, this works great. But if the client is launched first, it will throw the error and crash. What I would like to do is be able to launch either side first, and have it wait for the connection. The client is obviously the issue, so i am trying:

```
 bool bConnected;

    std::string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream* stream;

    while (!bConnected)
    {
        stream = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream(ip, "4444");
        if (!stream)
        {
            std::cout << "cannot find datastream" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
            //throw std::runtime_error("can't connect");
        }

        if (stream)
        {
            bConnected = true;
        }

    }
```

This will not compile, giving me an error on `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream* stream`, with `Error  C4703   potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'stream' used`. I have tried:

`boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream* stream = nullptr;`
`boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream* stream = NULL`;

both compile, but crash.  How can I have the client wait for the server, in this situation?

Comment: I doubt you get an *error*, but rather a *warning*. It's impossible to say though, because you haven't shown us the actual output of the build which we really need (in full and complete).

Comment: What you *do* use uninitialized and which is most likely the reason for the *warning* (and the crash) is the variable `bConnected`. The value of uninitialized local variables is *indeterminate* (and will seem random) and using them in any way without initialization is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: updated with the actual warning that is stopping compilation. `Error  C4703   potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'stream' used`

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude said. Try `bool bConnected = false;` (and `stream=nullptr` for good measure). Reason: if bConnected happens to be true, the whole while-block is skipped and stream is and the following code will access the uninitialized stream

Comment: I have adjusted the bool to init as false, and I see the same error. Please see the updated question, the error is related to the `stream` variable.

Comment: Ah, adding both bool `bConnected = false;` and `stream=nullptr` stops the crash. thank you. But, now the `if(!stream)` bool is never triggered, so the application does not keep trying to connect.

Comment: Now you have *another* problem, and that is with the condition checking the `stream` variable. It is a pointer so `if (!stream)` doesn't check the success of the connection, but check if the *pointer* is a null pointer or not. The condition `!stream` is equal to `stream == nullptr` (and plain `stream` in a condition is equal to `stream != nullptr`). To solve this, think about how you can get the object a pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Ah got it. `if (!*stream)` works. Thank you very much for your help, and patience.

Answer (score 4):

Never use `new`¹. Because as you commented, `if (!*stream)` ***compiles*** but it leaks resource like there's no tomorrow.

In this case:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4477139c8ca4a0f7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    tcp::iostream stream;

    do {
        std::cout << "Connecting...\n";

        stream.clear();
        stream.connect("127.0.0.1", "4444");

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    } while (!stream);

    std::cout << "Connected! " << stream.rdbuf();
}
```

Which prints:

```
Connecting...
Connecting...
Connecting...
Connecting...
Connecting...
Connecting...
Connected! Hello world
```

---

¹ unless you're writing a low-level resource wrapper for your library interface.

Comment: I like your use of netcat on Coliru :) Didn't know it was available

Comment: @djf it's limited to loopback though